# How to formally say that I am a handyman (in resume)?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expression-choice

I wanted to add a word that says I am very good and comfortable with handling tools and equipment and can perform many works that require handcrafting, building, assembling, constructing, etc. I know that "handyman" is a good word, but not for a resume. Is there a synonym or an expression that would state this point? I want to emphasize on assertive handling of tools, rather than capable of performing kinds of jobs.

Comment: Skilled artisan.

Comment: @YosefBaskin "Skilled artisan" seems to imply a person that creates art, an artist? I am rather a tech guy that can use files, drills, knives and other tools, soldering to make/prototype things. English is not my fist language, so I can not sense this meaning well.

Comment: An artisan is not an artist but a craftsman. It's a strong term for anyone like a Persian rug maker or a potter. Skilled means you are better than average. You may have heard _artisanal cheese_ as a term for cheese that is not art, but a lovingly made specialty.

Comment: Perhaps a word in Yosef's second comment, _craftsman_, would be another option.

Comment: "Skilled Artisan" or "craftsman" would imply that you're good at making something specific. It would be a good idea to put what that thing is in your resume (unless it's a bad idea).

Comment: If you really don't want to use "handyman" in your CV, I can suggest "versatile carpenter and repairman."  And then be specific, for example plumbing, electrical work, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is:

### [Jack of All Trades](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/jack_of_all_trades/define)

- A person able to do a variety of different jobs acceptably well.
- A man skilled in various odd jobs and other small tasks.

---

And also:

### [Factotum](http://www.yourdictionary.com/factotum)

- A person hired to do all sorts of work; handyman.

---

And, as several have commented, I also vote for:

### [Crafstman](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/craftsman)

- A person who is skilled in a particular craft.

---

And adding a descriptive term to **craftsman** may help. As in:

### General Craftsman

or

### Multipurpose Craftsman

Comment: I would avoid _jack of all trades_ on a CV, not only because it's rather colloquial but also because of its association with the continuing _master of none_.